# bootstrap javascript not working angular 14

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

i added bootstrap to angular 14 project like this:
`
"styles": [

```
           "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

`

But all accordions and dropdows does not works (all libraries were install by npm and exist - i checked).

what is the problem?

Comment: Did you consider using Angular Material (replacing Bootstrap)? Although it isn't a direct answer to the question it might be a good advice because Angular Material works much more seemlessly together with Angular.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap command as it sets up all the needed configuration for you instead of trying to add it manually.

Comment: i used ng-bootstrap and it works. Thanks